# Bind JQuery filter bar to sorted list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a JSON array loaded into a JQuery mobile list. I have 4 radio buttons to sort the list. All working.

Plus, I have a filter bar to search through the sorted results. So let's say I sorted my list by price ascending, I can search the list with the filter bar. But if I click price descending, the list automaticaly refresh to default.

So what i'm trying to do is sort by name ascending, filter through the results with the search bar, and if I click another sort button, the list doesnt refresh.

I hope you can understand me, I explained this as clearly as I can. Heres my code :

```
var productList = {"products": [
    {"brand": "brand1", "description": "Product 1", "price": "03.25 "},
    {"brand": "brand2", "description": "Product 4", "price": "01.10 "},
    {"brand": "brand3", "description": "Product 3", "price": "04.21 "},
    {"brand": "brand4", "description": "Product 2", "price": "15.24 "},
    {"brand": "brand5", "description": "Product 5", "price": "01.52 "},
    {"brand": "brand6", "description": "Product 6", "price": "12.01 "},
    {"brand": "brand7", "description": "Product 7", "price": "05.24 "}
```

]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

```
console.debug('ready');

$('#sort > input[type = "radio"]').next('label').click( function(event, el) {


    console.debug($(event.currentTarget).prev('input').attr('id'));

    sortID = $(event.currentTarget).prev('input').attr('id');

    refresh(sortID);
});
```

});

function refresh(sortID) {

var list = $("#productList").listview();
$(list).empty();


var prods = productList.products.sort(function(a, b) {

    switch (sortID) {
    case 'sort-a-z':
       return a.description > b.description;

    case 'sort-z-a':
        return a.description < b.description;

    case 'sort-price-up':
        return parseInt(a.price) > parseInt(b.price);

    case 'sort-price-down':
        return parseInt(a.price) < parseInt(b.price);

    default:
        return a.description > b.description;

}

});
$.each(prods, function() {
    list.append("<li>" + this.description + "  :       " + this.price + "</li>");
});

$(list).listview("refresh");

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is exactly the problem but I do know you shouldn't be using parseInt to compare the prices like that.

- parseInt  stops when it sees a nondigit.
- If the first character passed to parseInt is 0, then the string is evaluated in base 8 instead of base 10. In base 8, 8 and 9 are not digits, so parseInt("08") and parseInt("09") produce 0 as their result.

parseInt can take a radix parameter, so that parseInt("08", 10) produces 8.

for the best result use parseFloat and then multiply the result by 100 to produce a whole number - then when you'll compare the prices you'll avoid all quircks of the javascript floating point system.

beyond that the code you shared looks okay to me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, always looking to improve my code. Appreciate the help.